# JMeter: Run concurrent http requests based on user defined variable

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, load-testing

I have a User Defined Variable `numberOfUsers` in my test plan. I'm extracting from the DB number of users based on the `numberOfUsers` variable, than I'm using the `Foreach Controller` to make login request for each user to get a token for making API requests to my server.

Now, I want to use the tokens I got in the `Foreach Controller` to make concurrent requests to specific API. Each request will be for another user using his unique token.
How can I do this? I saw that the `Foreach controller` cannot execute requests concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Move the logic of obtaining the number of users and getting the tokens into [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
2. After logging in store the token for each user into JMeter Properties via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) so you would have the following properties defined:

   ```
   token_1=some-token
   token_2=some-other-token
   numberOfUsers=number-of-users-from-database
   ```
3. Once done you will be able to use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function to read the values from the properties like `${__P(numberOfUsers,)}`

   [image]

   And the tokens can be accessed using the aforementioned __P() function with [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function combination: `${__P(token_${__threadNum},)}`

   [image]